# requestAnimationFrame attached to App object not Window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have set up the following jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZbhQY/4/

Im using a small requestAnimationFrame polyfill and returning the result to window.reqeuestAnimFrame this all works fine and all calls to this function work as expected.

If i change this to return to game.reqeuestAnimFrame and replace all calls to window.reqeuestAnimFrame to the new game.reqeuestAnimFrame it no longer works.

Could someone please explain why this is the case and what i could do in order to make this work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` must have a context of `window` to function properly.

You can rewrite your call as:

```
game.requestAnimFrame.call(win, game.run);
```

and it will function as expected.

The error you were running into is because `requestAnimationFrame` expects its context (`this`) to be `window`, but instead its context was `game`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbhQY/5/

Alternatively, you could rewrite your `requestAnimFrame` getter like so:

```
game.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
        var rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };

        return function(callback){
            rAF.call(window, callback);
        };            
    })();
```

This would allow you to call `game.requestAnimFrame(game.run)` as you would expect.

Comment: many thanks too =) I was hanging on this for two hours now. Your solution with call is as simple as brilliant. I didn't know, that rAF must be in a window context. Now everything is clear for me =)