# requestAnimationFrame type error in object

Tags: html, object, canvas, window, requestanimationframe

hi i'm trying to use requestAnimationFrame for my game and I actually use this code below, but as you can see ".bind()" create every loop a new function that slow down my game... I'm looking for a "efficient" solution for the best perfomance, thank you in advance :D

```
function myClass() {
  this.loop = function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));

    /* here myGameLoop */
  }

  this.loop();
}
```

above code works but is slow.. instead this "standard" code give me "Type error":

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this);
```

---

I have also found e tried this Q&A: [requestAnimationFrame attached to App object not Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591250/requestanimationframe-attached-to-app-object-not-window) works just ONE time then give the same "Type error" :(

try if you don't believe me: http://jsfiddle.net/ygree/1 :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the whole story of your object (what else is in there); you could simplify life by just doing this:

```
function myClass() {

    var iHavAccessToThis = 1;

    function loop() {

        iHavAccessToThis++;

        /* here myGameLoop */

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();

    //if you need a method to start externally use this instead of the above line
    this.start = function() { loop() }

    //...
    return this;
}
```

Now you don't need to bind anything and you access local scope which is fast.

And then call:

```
var class1 = new myClass();
class1.start();
```

Comment: Since I'm writing a html5 framework, in the way you suggest, I have to duplicate all the "externally usable" methods and properties.

So... If I have 100 properties/methods, I have to write other 100 methods to returns this properties... not good really? anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @user2488460 sounds like a huge project. Please also consider upvote/accepting the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: it's not my first html5 framework ;) however I'm still looking for a better solution for this question :'(